# c++ vector one dimensional and two dimensional arrays value assignment

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I am confused about c++ two dimensioanal vectors

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    //First Code
    std::vector<int> oneDimArray;
    oneDimArray.push_back(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < oneDimArray.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << oneDimArray[i];
    }
    //Second Code
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> twoDimArray;
    twoDimArray[0].push_back(5);                          //Here giving error

    for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j : twoDimArray[i])
        {
            std::cout << j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to run this code **First Code** is working. But in **Second Code** i am getting vector out of range error while trying to push back. I guess at first i should say `twoDimArray`'s first size to it. But i dont know how. Because i am definig this `twoDimArray` in my `.h` file so if i do this i must do it there. Please can you help me?

Comment: Straight forward error. '''twoDimArrat''' has size 0. Hence accessing '''twoDimArray[0]''' is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of two reasons.

1. The vector you are trying to access is empty
2. You are trying to put an `int` into a vector that was supposed to hold `vector<int>`s.
   Fixed code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> oneDimArray;
    oneDimArray.push_back(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < oneDimArray.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << oneDimArray[i];
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> twoDimArray;
    twoDimArray.push_back(oneDimArray); //You can put a vector of ints in here

    for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j : twoDimArray[i])
        {
            std::cout << j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`twoDimArray[0].push_back(5)` is invalid because the vector had no size yet. After you have pushed back something, or done `twoDimArray.resize(`**new size here**`);`, then you can do that (as long as it isn't out of range).

Also, once a vector has size, you can access the elements of the vector inside the vector by going like `twoDimArray[0][0] = 1;`. That would give the first value of the first vector inside of the vector to get the value 1.

Comment: I was trying to do excatly what you say but i am confused when i came from different programming lanuage huh. Thank you sir